# Show that $13$ is the only prime such that $d(p(2p+1))=8$ and $2p+1$ is NOT semiprime where $d$ is the divisor counting function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

I would like to prove the following statement.

> Let $d$ be the divisor counting function and $p$ a prime number. Let
>   $X_8$ be the set of prime numbers $p$ such that $d(p(2p+1))=8$. Then
>   $X_8  = \{13\}\cup Y$ where $Y$ is the set of all
>   primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is semiprime.

Surely $13*(2*13+1) =13*3^3=351$. What I am trying to say is that $13$ is the only prime such that $d(p(2p+1))=8$ and $2p+1$ is ***NOT*** semiprime. A counter example  would suffice.

I would appreciate edits to make this question more succinct and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number to have 8 divisors it has to be like $p*q^3$ or $p*q*r$ where p,q,r are primes. Since you excluded semiprimes for 2p+1 then 2p+1 has to be $q^3$ meaning $$2p=q^3-1 => 2p=(q-1)(q^2+q+1)$$ and it's possible only for q=3 and p=13

Comment: How did you solve that equation and conclude that $q=3$ or $q=13$?

Comment: 2p has only 4 factors 1,2,p,2p since q-1 is lower then $q^2+q+1$ then q-1=1 or q-1=2 check them both and you'll see. 
But I have to correct myself cos number like $p^7$ also has 8 divisors but anyway $2p+1=p^6$ is impossible

Comment: Hmm I think I follow you. Since $2p+1 \neq qr$ we must have $p(2p+1) =pq^3$. So that $2p+1=q^3$. Then $2p =q^3-1 =(q-1)(q^2+q+1)$. Now $2p$ has as factors $1,2,p,2p$. Since $q-1<q^2+q+1$ we have that $q-1=1$ or $q-1 =2$. We take $q-1=2$ so that $q=3$ then $2p =2(3^2+3+1) =2(9+4)=2*13=26$ so that $p=13$.